# Firefox: allow pointer lock from any context

Tags: javascript, firefox, permissions, mouse-cursor, pointerlock

I need to lock the pointer but when I [requestPointerLock](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestPointerLock) it's telling me

> Request for pointer lock was denied because Element.requestPointerLock() was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler, and the document is not in full screen.

Or

> Request for pointer lock was denied because the document is not focused.

Which makes sense, but I'm making an app that needs to open with a locked pointer, can't wait for user interaction. Good news is I have complete control over the device, so I figured I would edit some `about:config` setting and I'd call it a day, but I can't seem to find the one.

How can I tell firefox to allow the pointer lock at any time?

Comment: I've peeked `https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/base/Document.cpp#14415` - maybe you can affect `aUserInputOrChromeCaller`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that requestPointerLock cannot be called automatically, it should be called from the user's callback, for example, when clicking on something.

You can call requestPointerLock() directly if the user has accepted a fullscreen request [see link](https://w3c.github.io/pointerlock).